# is it possible to sort an Array in my algorithm using the raw sort() method?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I am wondering if I can sort this Array like this:

```
[ 0 ,3, 1, 4, 0 ] =>   [ 1, 3, 4, 0, 0]
```

detailed rules:

- the array contains 0 and positive numbers.
- all the 0 are in the end.
- all the positive numbers are sorted in ascending order.

At the beginning , I used the js's raw sort function, like:

```
[0, 3, 1, 4, 0].sort(function(previous_value, former_value){
  if(previous_value == 0 && former_value != 0 ) {
      return 1;
    }else if (former_value == 0 && former_value != 0) {
      return -1;
    }else if (former_value == 0 && former_value == 0) {
      return 0;
    }else{
      return previous_value - former_value;
  }
})
```

However, I failed. I am wondering if is it possible to implement "my sorting algorithm" using the `sort` function? e.g.:

```
[0, 3, 1, 4, 0].sort(function(previous_value, former_value){
    //code goes here
})
```

And it will get the correct answer:

```
[1, 3, 4, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Do you need it using ONLY sort function, or can I implement it in any other way?

Comment: I just tested your function and seems to work as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/mrlew/j5qbcgch/

Comment: Your code snippet is confusing and incorrect. The variables are named "previous" and "former" (almost synonyms, confusing), and you are only checking the "former" one in the two `else if` branches where you should have used both.

Comment: @user4815162342  yes! you are right! the "previous" and "former" doesn't look good.  I just don't want to name them as "a", "b"  or  "x/y".   I will check it out!

Comment: There is a reason for the traditional names - you cannot assign *meaning* to these elements (since the sorting algorithm gives you completely arbitrary array members), so the names convey that. In a sense, they really are just some a/b/x/y which you need to compare, no more to it than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give `0` to higher priority

```js
console.log(
  [0, 3, 1, 4, 0].sort(function(a, b) {
    return a === b ? 0 : (a === 0 ? 1 : (b === 0 ? -1 : a - b));
  })
);
```

With expanded if condition

```js
console.log(
  [0, 3, 1, 4, 0].sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a === b)
      return 0;
    if (a === 0)
      return 1;
    if (b === 0)
      return -1;
    return a - b;
  })
);
```

Answer (score 2):

All you need is to force your comparator to treat 0 as the highest number.

```
function compareNumbers(a, b) {
  if (a === 0) {
   return 1;
  }
  if (b === 0) {
   return -1;
  }
  return a - b;
}
```

And now you just do `[0, 3, 1, 4, 0].sort(compareNumbers)`.

Only because it is tagged with [algorithms](/questions/tagged/algorithms) tag, I would say that if you expect your array to be large and have high number of zeros, it might make sense to create a smaller array of not zero elements, sort it and append it with zeros to the original length.

Comment: Thanks a lot! your answer is also correct, however I could choose only answer.    good job!

Comment: this may increase number of steps in `sort()` :) , https://jsfiddle.net/9rxnddbw/

Comment: Siwei, not a problem. He was faster :-). @PranavCBalan my point was not to be as concise as possible, but to explain what exactly I am doing with a comparator and why do I do this.

Comment: @SalvadorDali in case both values are `0` it returns `1`, just that increase the number of steps, it can be fixed by `if (a !== b && a === 0)` or `if (b !== 0 && a === 0)`

Answer (score 1):

While you have already a solution, you could use the [logical OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) operator for a falsy value (like `0`) and give it a default value (like `Infinity`).

This moves zero to the end, because the default value is bigger than all other values.

```js
var array = [ 0 ,3, 1, 4, 0 ];

array.sort(function (a,b) {
    return (a || Infinity) - (b || Infinity);
});

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be my solution with logical short circuits

```js
var a = [0, 3, 1, 4, 0].sort((a,b) => !a && 1 || !b && -1 || a-b);
console.log(a);
```